# Camera Lock-On behind player while targeting enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Something similar to either Rocket League or Kingdom Hearts, where the camera locks onto the target but it still keeps the player in the center of the screen. I've placed the camera as a child of the player, but after trying out various solutions from others I'm still unable to position the camera correctly.

```
public List<Transform> targets;

private void EnemyCam()
{
    Vector3 centerPoint = GetCenterPoint();
    transform.LookAt(centerPoint);

    Vector3 newPos = centerPoint;

    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, newPos, ref 
    velocity, smoothTime);
}

private Vector3 GetCenterPoint()
{
    if (targets.Count == 1)
        return targets[0].position;

    var bounds = new Bounds(targets[0].position, Vector3.zero);

    for (int i = 0; i < targets.Count; ++i)
        bounds.Encapsulate(targets[i].position);

    return bounds.center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving you camera by script, it shouldn't be child of the moving player at the same time. You are setting up some position from script, but at the same time, this position is modified also by parent object so final result is unpredictable.

Comment: How do I go about doing it then? I've tried removing it as a child, when there's no enemy the camera seems ok, but the moment I place an enemy the camera looks directly at the centerpoint of both targets, which still leaves my question unsolved.